# How to merge every N rows in a csv file using phyton pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have long rows of data where each of them contains a single character of a number and I want to merge every 5 rows of data into 1 using python.

> for example:

```
A      Result

1      12335
2      23352
3      33525
3      35251
5      ...
2      ...
5      ... 
1      ...
```

the first result contains rows from `1 to 5` and the second result contains rows from `2 to 6`. Can someone help me with that? Any answer would be appreciated!

Comment: It's better if you include desired output in the question. It's doubtful.

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 1):

something like this should work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'input' : ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']})
df['result'] = df['input']
for i in range (1,6):
    df['result'] = df['result'] + df['input'].shift(-i)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Yash! really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This also works but not very elegant

```
dz = df.iloc[0::5,:].reset_index(drop=True)+df.iloc[1::5,:].reset_index(drop=True)+df.iloc[2::5,:].reset_index(drop=True)+df.iloc[3::5,:].reset_index(drop=True)+df.iloc[4::5,:].reset_index(drop=True)
```